# getting undefined method `set' for dropdown using watir

Tags: watir

```
require 'watir'  

ie = Watir::Browser.new  
ie.goto "http://www.wallpapers.com/windows/Wallpapers/Animals/Dogs"  


ie.select(:id, "ctl00_CPH1_ctl00_ddlSortExpression").flash   
ie.select(:id, "ctl00_CPH1_ctl00_ddlSortExpression").set("Newest")  


C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:433:in `method_missing': undefined method `set' for #<Watir::SelectList:0x31be0b8> (NoMethodError)
        from sample.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

also tried with same result:

```
ie.select(:id, "ctl00_CPH1_ctl00_ddlSortExpression").to_subtype.set("Newest")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.select()` instead:

```
ie.select(:id, "ctl00_CPH1_ctl00_ddlSortExpression").select("Newest")
```

In Watir 3.0, `.set()` no longer exists for select lists. Not sure if it is a bug or removed on purpose.